# How to initialized GoogleApiClient inside a UI thread

Tags: android, google-api, ui-thread

I am calling :

```
 GoogleApiClient client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this.context)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
  client.connect();
```

inside a UI thread and *onConnected(Bundle bundle)* is not called.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: did you check `onConnectionSuspended` or `onConnectionFailed` are not getting called?

Answer (score 0):

@Saar peer, You could try another workaround. Use a `Service` which implements `GoogleApiClient`and it's `ConnectionCallbacks`. Inside `onStart` (or `onStartCommand`) of Service, connect `googleApiClient`.

```
GoogleApiClient client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(ServiceName.class)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
  client.connect();
```